# how to solving this Differential equation?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I need help solving the following differential equation:

$${{y'}} =  {{2x} \over {\cos^2x}} $$

Comment: have you done any work on this?

Comment: You need to integrate $2x\sec^2 x$. As a first step, use integration by parts, $u=2x$, $dv=\sec^2 x\,dx$.

Comment: This is not really a differential equation...

Comment: thanks all but I need to use ( Separation of variables )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y'=\frac{2x}{\cos^2 x}$$
$$y= \int \frac{2x}{cos^2 x} dx.$$
Integrate by parts:

$u=2x$, $du=2dx$

$dv=\sec^2 x dx,$ $v=\tan x$
$$y=2x \tan {x}-2\int \tan xdx =2x \tan {x}+\ln|\cos x|+C$$

Comment: thanks all but I need to use ( Separation of variables )

Comment: @barracuda The variables are already separated.

Comment: The first equality *is* using separation of variables, because it's already separated for you.  Write it as $$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} = \frac{2x}{\cos^2(x)}$$ and then separate by integrating both sides as follows:
$$y = \int \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}\,\text{d}x = \int\frac{2x}{\cos^2(x)}\,\text{d}x$$
(we can wait to add the arbitrary constant of integration at the end).  Then compute the integral on the right, as in the answer above.  That's how you would solve this.